# Why is my collection view empty when I should have a bunch of reusable cells?

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have the following code:

```
class FinalImageViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    var not: [UIImage?] = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "silly5"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "special16")]
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return not.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CVImageView", for: indexPath) as! CVCell
        cell.cellImageView.image = not[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(ImagesOnClick)
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(CVCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CVImageView")
    }
    
}
```

And my cell:

```
class CVCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var cellImageView: UIImageView!
    
}
```

Then in my storyboard I have set the imageView tag to 3, the cell identifier to `CVImageView`, but when I run the project the collection view is just all white and no items are showing. By the way if you're wondering what the `ImagesOnClick` is, it is just an array of the users selected images.

Comment: Probably need to add: `func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {  return 1 }`

Comment: I just tried adding that and didn't work :(

Comment: Where is `ImagesOnClick` populated? By the way `viewWithTag` is outdated for a long time. Design a custom cell (an `UICollectionViewCell` subclass) with an outlet.

Comment: If you look at my question I have changed the code by creating a `UICollectionViewCell class` I have also changed `ImageOnClick` too `not` (not is an array of two image literals) just for testing purposes but still getting the same results of nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your class name in storyboard, it should look like this

[image: You can find your class name in storyboard, it should look like this in the screenshot]

```
class FinalImageViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return ImagesOnClick.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CVImageView", for: indexPath) as! CVImageCell //replace CVImageCell with your cell class name
    cell.imageView.image = ImagesOnClick[indexPath.row] //replace imageView with your image view name with tag=3
    return cell
}


@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(ImagesOnClick)
    collectionView.register(CVImageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CVImageView") //replace CVImageCell with your cell class name
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
}

}
```

Comment: This did not do anything unless there's something I should put in the `Cell View Class`

Comment: I just uploaded a picture in the answer above, please take a look. I hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: Please view my most recent comment under my question

Comment: try to set a background color to your cell smth like: cell.backgroundColor = .red if you can see anything after that it means that maybe the problem is with your image view array

Comment: I fixed it! I am all set

Comment: what was the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest I just restarted and followed the tutorial again